# Is there any any other way to find in array pair of numbers whose sum are k?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of integers and a number k. Is it necessary to determine whether there are two numbers in the array whose sum is k?

```js
function findPairs(nums, k) {
  var s = [];
  var length = nums.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (s[nums[i]] === k - nums[i]) {
      console.log(nums[i], k - nums[i])
      return true;
    } else {
      s[k - nums[i]] = nums[i];
    }
  }
  return false;
}

var nums = [10, 15, 3, 7]
var k = 17

console.log(findPairs(nums, k))
```

why my code is not working?

Comment: i would expecte to see some kind of nested loop going on here...

Comment: I'm confused; your code seems to work fine for me? The output is "7 10 / true"; is that not correct?

Comment: After VLAZ "Fixed"  it the code seems to work

Comment: Wow, it does work. And very belatedly I see why: `s` tracks the numbers needed later. Will have to remember that trick.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder admittedly for large values of `k` this approach becomes _very_ inefficient. Should probably use an object or `Map` instead of an array.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Indeed. Though the JS engine will deoptimize the array to not literally be an array fairly early on, I'd expect.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the engine though. Array exotic objects do some very unexpected things when not used as intended in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you had a syntax error or forgot to actually declare a function, since the code in the current version of your question appears to work as expected.

As an aside, I would suggest using an object or a `Set` instead of an array to store the other pair, because for large values of `k`, your `s` array may consume a lot of memory on some JavaScript engines as a result.

```js
function findPairs(nums, k) {
  var s = {};
  var length = nums.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (s[nums[i]] === k - nums[i]) {
      console.log(nums[i], k - nums[i]);
      return true;
    }

    s[k - nums[i]] = nums[i];
    console.log(s); // see the lookup table after each iteration
  }

  return false;
}

var nums = [10, 15, 3, 7];
var k = 17;

console.log(findPairs(nums, k));
```

Answer (score -2):

Functional solution

```js
const findPairs = (nums, k) =>
  nums
    .flatMap((v, i, arr) => arr.slice(i + 1).map(w => [v, w]))
    .filter(pair => pair[0] + pair[1] === k);

console.log(findPairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 5));
```